# Document Complete Event Is not Raising in Internet explorer 11

Tags: c#, mshtml, shdocvw

Got one very weird scenario on Internet explorer 11. I have written one C# automated program for Internet explorer which was working fine till IE 10, now suddenly from IE 11, document complete stopped to raise more them 8 out of 10 times.

Just take an example of below code.

it will show Message box for the first time then it will never show that.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SHDocVw;

namespace IE11_POC
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        InternetExplorer IE;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        IE = new InternetExplorer();
        IE.Visible = true;

        IE.DocumentComplete += IE_DocumentComplete;
        IE.Navigate("http://stackoverflow.com/");

    }


    void IE_DocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(URL.ToString());
    }

}
```

}

Can any one please help me how to do this?

Comment: Can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: have the same issue with python script, it worked with ie8